# Where to find a good Google Play app policy generators

Tags: google-play, app-store, privacy-policy

I'm planning on publishing an app on Google Play that uses AdMob and location data to draw pins on an in-app Google Map and need a privacy policy. I'm not sure how to make one so I thought I would use a policy generator for now until I can see if I can afford to have a lawyer write one up.

So the question is what privacy policy generator should I use?

Answer (score 1):

I use this [generator](https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/) it is very good. if you have Facebook login in your app you may need to add a paragraph to enable user to retrieve and/or delete their data from your app, usually I add an email for people who wants to remove their data and that's it.